# Cordova in-app-browser engine

Tags: cordova

After some investigation it seems that the in-app-webview in Cordova actually ships a browser in the APK. Is this correct? If yes, which browser engine and version is this running on? I cannot find this information anywhere. Seems also rather important for (security) updates and the likes

Answer (score 3):

> Is this correct?

No. By default, Cordova uses the built-in system webview.

On iOS, it uses built-in UIWebView (deprecated as of iOS 12) or you can use the newer (built-in) WKWebView by installing [cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine).

On Android 4.4 and below it uses the old (built-in, non-updating) Android system webview; on Android 5+ uses the (built-in, self-updating) Chrome webview.

Because the Android 4.x system webview is buggy and non-updating, the [Crosswalk project](https://crosswalk-project.org/) arose, which does bundle a Chromium webview with the APK. The idea being to give more modern webview capabilities and better performance on old Android 4 devices. The downsides are increased APK size (~20Mb), installation size (~80Mb) and memory usage.

There is a [Cordova Crosswalk plugin](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/) which enables Crosswalk to be used as the webview by Cordova apps.

However, the Crosswalk project is [now deprecated and no longer maintained](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html) so as you rightly point out, it will not get security updates or new features (e.g. service workers).

So unless you care about supporting Android 4.x, don't use Crosswalk.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Do you have any idea how to use the Chrome/Chromuim web view embedded in a cordova app?